# Why Kubernetes mounted volume files turning into directory inside the pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, volume, mount, mounted-volumes

I need to copy a zip file from my host machine to pod/container. for that  using hostPath volume as follows

```
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/tmp/delivery/AB_Database.zip"
      name: db-volume
      subPath: AB_Database.zip
  volumes:
  - name: db-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /delivery/oracle
```

but when I check inside pod AB_Database.zip is seen as directory.

Comment: A `hostPath:` mount looks for a file on the node the pod is running on.  That's usually not your local system, and different replicas of the same deployment can be running on different nodes.  I'd try to avoid a `hostPath:` mount in almost all cases, except for some admin-related things that run in DaemonSets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due you have given name in **subpath**

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/tmp/delivery/AB_Database.zip"
      name: db-volume
      subPath: AB_Database.zip
  volumes:
  - name: db-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /delivery/oracle
```

Subpath work like

```
volumeMounts:
- name: test-path
  mountPath: /a/b/c
  subPath: d
```

inside `c` directory you have some files **1.txt**, **2.txt** thn **subpath** will rewrite those content in `c` and create new directory `d`

You can check more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath

if you just want to mount the zip into the POD you can do something like with **mountpath**

```
- mountPath: /var/local/aaa/1.txt
  name: myfile
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath-fileorcreate-example